# PrintWriter and byte[] problem

Tags: java

```
byte[] data = (byte[])opBinding.execute();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);    
out.println(data);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

but instead of text i get @84654. How can i add byte[] to PrintWriter? I need byte[] and not strinf becouse i have encoing problems with čćžšđ

Comment: Do you know what encoding your `byte[]` data is in?  If so you can use `String foo = new String(data, "UTF-8")` or similar.

Comment: no need for `flush()`, `colse()` is enough

Comment: sometimes utf-8, sometimes windows-1250. becouse of this i store text into blob. Then i read it into byte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the outputstream directly to write the bytes.

```
outputStream.write(byte[] b);
```

Answer (score 4):

`PrintWriter` is meant for *text* data, not *binary* data.

It sounds like you should quite possibly be converting your `byte[]` to a `String`, and then writing that string out - assuming the `PrintWriter` you're writing to uses an encoding which supports the characters you're interested in.

You'll also need to know the encoding that the original text data has been encoded in for the `byte[]`, in order to successfully convert to text to start with.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that your code calls (implicitly) `data.toString()` before returning the result to your `println` statement.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
byte[] data = (byte[])opBinding.execute();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);    
out.println(new String(data));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: this is ok but then is encoding problem.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me.. when i used

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(System.out);
```

Also it converts the byte data to String using `toString()` method.. So it may be a reason for your encoding problem